# Number of different rolls of K N-sided dice

Tags: dice, j, tacit-programming, oeis

I needed to calculate the number of different possible rolls that could arise from rolling K dice, each with N-sides. My definition of roll is that something like {1, 1, 2, 3, 4} is equivalent to {1, 4, 3, 1, 2} (order doesn't matter), but not to {1, 1, 3, 3, 3} (they're not the same set of results). For example: Yahtzee is a game involving rolls of 5 6-sided dice—at least initially, before rerolls—and the number of different rolls is thus 252. The case when N = K leads to [OEIS sequence A001700](http://oeis.org/A001700).

If I'm not horribly mistaken, this is given by "(N-1+K) choose (N-1)", or equivalently, "(N+K-1) choose K", which is `K ! <: K + N` in J. This leads me to four different tacit representations:

- `d =: ([ ! [: <: +)`. Simple train, without parentheses, though I need to use a cap.
- `d =: ([ (! <:) +)`. No cap, but parenthesizing the inner hook.
- `d =: (] !&<: +)`. Only a three verb train, but using a Compose. It uses the `(<: N) ! <: K + N` version.
- `d =: (([ ! +) * ] % +)`. This one rewrites "C(N+K-1, K)" as "C(N+K, K) * N / (N+K)". It's uglier, but in the 0 dice of 0 sides case, it gives 0 instead of 1, which is arguably a less nonsensical answer.

Which of these is the most "J-ish" solution?

Also, the monadic case for all of these is meaningless: `1 0 0 0 0 ...` for the first three and `0 1 1 1 ...` for the fourth. A more logical monad for this verb would be the reflexive, as given by `d~`, so would it be better to define this verb as `(d~ : d)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be:

```
d =: ([ (! <:) +)
```

and to add a monadic option to the dyadic

```
d =: d~ : ([ (! <:) +) NB. 4 d 5 ( 4 rolls of 5 sided dice : 70 possible combinations)
```

I would add the comment including sample arguments and an expected purpose to save me time were I to stumble across it later.

Of course, the final version would be the choice if 0 d 0 were to return 0, even if it does look a little more complicated.

Comment: I share your preference. If zero rolls or dice are desired to produce zero as the result, I'd make <code> [ (! <:) + </code> the right tine of this wider fork: <code> *&amp;* * ([ (! <:) +) </code>

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the comment actually display the code. To the left of the original verb should be star-ampersand-star-space-star. (The space is decorative, not semantic, of course.)

Comment: Oh, so you mean `(*&* * [ (! <:) +)`? Now there's an idea. You can't just signum the product, because I think 1 way to roll 0 dice with N sides makes combinatorical sense. But that idea leads us to `(*@] * [ (! <:) +)`, which fits the bill. Nice!

Comment: The code you came up with here was my first idea, actually, but I didn't understand the distinction you're making between rolling no dice and having no sides, so I generalized.

Comment: Well if `(*@] * [ (! <:) +)` fits the bill then `(* *) @ ([ (! <:) +)` should as well. And if zero sided die could only be thrown one way then `( (* *) (! <:) + )` would work as well.